# Javascript templating library that infers used variables and dependencies

Tags: javascript, templates, dependency-management, templating, templating-engine

Is there a Javascript templating library that automatically infers the variables used in the template and the possible dependencies among them? If I for example have a template that looks like this ([Handlebars](http://www.handlebarsjs.com/) syntax):

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{body}}
  </div>
</div>
</script>
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
template.vars() => {title: "", body: ""}
```

The reason I would like this functionality is that I would like to be able to generate a form with fields reflecting the variables needed to complete the template.

Comment: That's a good idea.  Depending on what the template "inclusions" allow you to do, it might get kind-of complicated.

Comment: You could check out KnockOut.js or Backbone.js I think they handle this kinds of things.

Comment: I did. KnockOut.js handles dependencies in the viewmodel, but not in the template. Backbone.js depends on Underscore.js' template method which does not support inferring free variables from the template.

Comment: @mac just to correct, Backbone.js does not depend on underscore.js's template method, backbone depends on underscore, but you do not have to use it's templating method per se, you can just as well use jquery templating, mustache, ... any other framework you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet (edit at http://jsfiddle.net/CfaAW/2/) uses a Regex to find the simple `{{var}}` syntax, and will also look for `.` to handle Handlebars Paths.

```
function extractObjectFromTemplate(source) {
    var handlebarsRegex = /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g;
    var varObject = {};
    var varArray, ns, o, i, len;
    while ((varArray = handlebarsRegex.exec(source)) !== null) {
        ns = varArray[1].split('.');
        o = varObject;
        for (i = 0, len = ns.length; i < len; i++) {
            o = o[ns[i]] = o[ns[i]] || (i == len - 1 ? "" : {});
        }
    }

    return varObject;
}
```

On your template, a `JSON.stringify(extractObjectFromTemplate(source))` gives you this:

```
{"title":"","body":""}
```

and with Handlebars Paths in your template

```
<h1>{{title.h1}}</h1>
<h2>{{title.h2}}</h2>
<div class="body">
  {{body}}
</div>
```

you will get the nested properties

```
{"title":{"h1":"","h2":""},"body":""}
```